# Hibernate mapping OneToMany through Annotation

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many

Dear Friends I have two entities: Employee and Department associated with OneToMany association. i.e. An employee can work in more than one Department. I created two employee and two department. Both employee work in the same departments. When I am saving these entities I am getting this exception. I have given here full code of my program. Thanks in advance for helping anyone.
            Code:--

--   Department Entity ---

```
package anno;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="annoDept")
public class AnnoDept {


    @Id
    @Column(name = "deptid")
    private Integer anid;
    @Column(name = "deptname")
    private String anname;

    public Integer getAnid() {
        return anid;
    }

    public void setAnid(Integer anid) {
        this.anid = anid;
    }

    public String getAnname() {
        return anname;
    }

    public void setAnname(String anname) {
        this.anname = anname;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
         if(!(obj instanceof AnnoDept))
             return false;
          if(((AnnoDept)obj).getAnid()==this.getAnid() && ((AnnoDept)obj).getAnname().equalsIgnoreCase(this.getAnname()))
              return true;
          return false;

    }
}



--Employee Entity code: --

package anno;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="annoEmp")
public class AnnoEmp {
     @Id
    private Integer empid;

     @Column(name="EName")
    private String empname;
     public Integer getEmpid() {
        return empid;
    }
    public void setEmpid(Integer empid) {
        this.empid = empid;
    }
    public String getEmpname() {
        return empname;
    }
    public void setEmpname(String empname) {
        this.empname = empname;
    }
    public Set<AnnoDept> getDepts() {
        return depts;
    }
    public void setDepts(Set<AnnoDept> depts) {
        this.depts = depts;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    private Set<AnnoDept> depts=new HashSet<AnnoDept>();
}

-- hibernate.cfg.xml file code: --

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
  <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
  <property name="connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="connection.password">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.format_query">true</property>
  <mapping class="anno.AnnoEmp"/>
  <mapping class="anno.AnnoDept"/>

 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>





--Test code:--

package anno;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

public class AnnoTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    SessionFactory sf=new AnnotationConfiguration().configure("mypack/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
    Session hs=sf.openSession();
    Transaction tx=hs.beginTransaction();

    AnnoDept dept=new AnnoDept();
    dept.setAnid(100);dept.setAnname("HR");
    AnnoDept dept3=new AnnoDept();
    dept3.setAnid(300);dept3.setAnname("Admin");
    Set<AnnoDept> deptset1=new HashSet<AnnoDept>();

    AnnoEmp e1=new AnnoEmp();
    e1.setEmpid(10);e1.setEmpname("Pinku");
    deptset1.add(dept);deptset1.add(dept3);
    e1.setDepts(deptset1);hs.save(e1);
    AnnoEmp e2=new AnnoEmp();
    e2.setEmpid(20);e2.setEmpname("Vijay");

    e2.setDepts(deptset1);
    hs.save(e2);

    tx.commit();
    hs.close();
    sf.close();
    }

}

-- Exception ---

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Hibernate: select annodept_.deptid, annodept_.deptname as deptname1_ from annoDept annodept_ where annodept_.deptid=?
Hibernate: select annodept_.deptid, annodept_.deptname as deptname1_ from annoDept annodept_ where annodept_.deptid=?
Hibernate: insert into annoEmp (EName, empid) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into annoDept (deptname, deptid) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into annoDept (deptname, deptid) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into annoEmp (EName, empid) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into annoEmp_annoDept (annoEmp_empid, depts_deptid) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into annoEmp_annoDept (annoEmp_empid, depts_deptid) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into annoEmp_annoDept (annoEmp_empid, depts_deptid) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into annoEmp_annoDept (annoEmp_empid, depts_deptid) values (?, ?)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
    at anno.AnnoTest.main(AnnoTest.java:39)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry '100' for key 2
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.executeBatch(ServerPreparedStatement.java:665)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:246)
    ... 8 more



Thanks
Dal Singar yadav
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not reuse your "deptset1" they are the SAME Set instance but each relationship is owned by separate AnnoEmp instances.  So you must have two different Set instances one for each AnnoEmp.  But you already have this in the entity class initialzers.  So why not just reuse that instance for each.  See below:

```
AnnoDept dept=new AnnoDept();
dept.setAnid(100);dept.setAnname("HR");
hs.save(dept);                  // ADDED LINE (TO HELP DEBUG)
hs.flush();                     // ADDED LINE (TO HELP DEBUG)

AnnoDept dept3=new AnnoDept();
dept3.setAnid(300);dept3.setAnname("Admin");
hs.save(dept3);                 // ADDED LINE (TO HELP DEBUG)
hs.flush();                     // ADDED LINE (TO HELP DEBUG)
Set<AnnoDept> deptset1;                  // REMOVED =new HashSet<AnnoDept>();

AnnoEmp e1=new AnnoEmp();
e1.setEmpid(10);e1.setEmpname("Pinku");
hs.save(e1);                    // ADDED LINE (TO HELP DEBUG)
hs.flush();                     // ADDED LINE (TO HELP DEBUG)
despset1 = e1.getDepts();                // ADDED LINE
deptset1.add(dept);deptset1.add(dept3);
//e1.setDepts(deptset1);                 // NOT NEEDED
//hs.save(e1);
hs.update(e1);                  // CHANGED TO UPDATE (TO HELP DEBUG)
hs.flush();                     // ADDED LINE (TO HELP DEBUG)

AnnoEmp e2=new AnnoEmp();
e2.setEmpid(20);e2.setEmpname("Vijay");
hs.save(e2);                    // ADDED LINE (TO HELP DEBUG)
hs.flush();                     // ADDED LINE (TO HELP DEBUG)
despset1 = e2.getDepts();                // ADDED LINE
deptset1.add(dept);deptset1.add(dept3);  // ADDED LINE
//e2.setDepts(deptset1);                 // NOT NEEDED
//hs.save(e2);
// WE ARE EXPECTING YOUR ERROR TO OCCUR HERE WHEN STORING THE NEW
// DATA IN THE 'Set' TO DATABASE
hs.update(e2);                  // CHANGED TO UPDATE (TO HELP DEBUG)
hs.flush();                     // ADDED LINE (TO HELP DEBUG)
```

Comment: Dear Darryl Miles thanks for viewing my question. But your answer is not right, I am getting the same exception again with your changed code.

Comment: Who created the database schema ?  Are using automatic schema generation ?  The actual error you get is relating to UNIQUE KEY constraint (which will happen if you re-use the 'Set' object instance).  The 'Set' is represented by the table ``annoEmp_annoDept``.  Try adding `hs.flush();` between every statement of code.  Try to find the exact line causing the problem.

Comment: I am sorry to say Darryl still given code is not working. Please run it on your system then share it with me.

Comment: Not working a poor description, maybe answer some of the questions put here ?  which line is causing the problem ? A new question have you checked your database tables are empty in your SQL server ?  Maybe you have some rows inserted from a previous debugging exercise ?

Comment: Dea Darryl Miles again this time code is not working. I am getting error at

Comment: Dea Darryl Miles again this time code is not working. I am getting error here:- hs.update(e2);     // CHANGED TO UPDATE (TO HELP DEBUG)
hs.flush();   //Exactly here I am getting exception
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry '300' for key 2